# How Can I Fix Jest's VSCode Extension's --testPathPattern Parameter?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

When I try to run my tests using the Jest VSCode extension at the project level, everything works fine.  It runs this command:

```
react-scripts test --env=jsdom "--testLocationInResults" "--json" "--useStderr" 
  "--outputFile" "C:\\Users\\MyName\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\jest_runner_project_name_myname_2.json" 
  "--no-coverage" "--reporters" "default" 
  "--reporters" "c:\\Users\\MyName\\.vscode\\extensions\\orta.vscode-jest-5.2.3\\out\\reporter.js" 
  "--colors" "--watchAll=false"
```

However, when I select a select a single file OR a single test within a file by clicking on the green "Run Test" icon (it looks like a play button) it runs this command:

```
react-scripts test --env=jsdom "--testLocationInResults" "--json" "--useStderr" 
  "--outputFile" "C:\\Users\\MyName\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\jest_runner_project_name_myname_2.json" 
  "--no-coverage" "--reporters" "default" 
  "--reporters" "c:\\Users\\MyName\\.vscode\\extensions\\orta.vscode-jest-5.2.3\\out\\reporter.js" 
  "--colors" "--watchAll=false" 
  "--testPathPattern" "c:\\\\git\\\\project-name\\\\src\\\\test\\\\util\\\\fileName\\.test\\.ts"
```

Obviously, the filename `\\\\fileName\\.test\\.ts` should be `\\\\fileName.test.ts`... but I don't know how to fix this. I see nothing in my `.vscode/settings.json` that impacts this:

```json
{
  "jest.autoRevealOutput": "on-run",
  "jest.autoRun": null,
  "jest.coverageColors": null,
  "jest.coverageFormatter": "DefaultFormatter",
  "jest.debugMode": false,
  "jest.disabledWorkspaceFolders": [],
  "jest.jestCommandLine": "",
  "jest.monitorLongRun": 60000,
  "jest.nodeEnv": null,
  "jest.parserPluginOptions": null,
  "jest.rootPath": "",
  "jest.shell": null,
  "jest.showCoverageOnLoad": false,
  "jest.testExplorer": null
},
```

nor anything from `package.json`:

```json
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.js",
      "src/**/*.ts",
      "src/**/*.tsx",
      "!src/test/**",
      "!src/styles/*.js",
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
      "lcov",
      "text",
      "text-summary"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 80,
        "functions": 81,
        "lines": 89,
        "statements": 88
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: This question got a `Close` vote - is there any way to see the justification so I can improve the question?